# Is There any way of Getting Form Information in App Engine in the GET Function

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

My question is rather simple...

In a def post(self) function for instance, I can use self.request.get to pull form information.

Is there any way I could accomplish the same thing within the 'def get(self)' function?

Thank you!!!

EDIT:

What I am trying to accomplish is sort of like facebook. If you could imagine a facebook wall, everyone has their own display pictures, which change dynamically. I'm trying to accomplish the same sort of thing... Too many variables would end up in the url I think if I choose to throw them in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def get(self):
    id = self.request.get('id')
```

Where you have it encoded in the URL like

```
/play?id=some_id
```

Lots more info at webapp2 [handlers](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html)

Comment: I don't think I could use that method. What I am trying to accomplish is sort of like facebook. If you could imagine a facebook wall, everyone has their own display pictures, which change dynamically. I'm trying to accomplish the same sort of thing... Too many variables would end up in the url I think if I choose this route.

Comment: then you have to use a POST where you can have a body I guess. Perhaps edit your question so it's more relevant to your ultimate goal instead?

Comment: Ok will do! I'll do some reading on it as well. Thanks for your time.